# SP07 - CAML Query between two dates

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, caml-query, caml

I have two **datetimeControllers** :

DateTimeControl dtFrom = new DateTimeControl();
    dtFrom.ID = "startDate";

DateTimeControl dtTo = new DateTimeControl();
    dtTo.ID = "endDate";

I want to get range **between** `dTfrom.SelectedDate` **and** `dtTo.SelectedDate` using CAML Query ...

```
SPList list = web.Lists["WayBill"];
SPQuery myquery = new SPQuery();

myquery.Query = "<OrderBy>" + 
                  "<FieldRef Name='wayNum' />" + 
                  "<FieldRef Name='Company' />" +
                  "<FieldRef Name='Project' />" +
                "</OrderBy>";
```

My query must be with `Lq` and `Gt`.

```
SPListItemCollection myitemcol = list.GetItems(myquery);

DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("wayNum");
table.Columns.Add("Title");
table.Columns.Add("Project");
table.Columns.Add("Company");
table.Columns.Add("CarNumber");
table.Columns.Add("NumWayBill");

foreach (SPListItem item in myitemcol)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row["wayNum"] = item["wayNum"].ToString();
    row["Title"] = item["Title"].ToString();
    row["Project"] = item["Project"].ToString();
    row["Company"] = item["Company"].ToString();
    row["CarNumber"] = item["CarNumber"].ToString();
    row["NumWayBill"] = item["NumWayBill"].ToString();
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}

DataView mydataview = new DataView(table);
table = mydataview.ToTable(true, "wayNum", "Title", "Project", "Company", "CarNumber", "NumWayBill");
tableRef.DataSource = table;
tableRef.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<Where><And><Gt><FieldRef Name='Date'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + dTfrom.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + "</Value></Gt><Lt><FieldRef Name='Date'/><Value Type='DateTime'>" + dtTo.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") + "</Value></Lt></And></Where>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another input:

When working with caml querys, you need to format your date time to the right format.

SPUtility gives you 2 important methods:

[SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createiso8601datetimefromsystemdatetime.aspx)

And

[SPUtility.CreateDateTimeFromISO8601DateTimeString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.createdatetimefromiso8601datetimestring.aspx)

They are really helpful when working with Caml and DateTimes.